# Using python, find combinations of numbers whose sum is as close as possible to another

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools, knapsack-problem

The problem:

1. I need to find three numbers in array2 that add up or comes as close as possible to each number in array3(it has to be three numbers).
2. Print the corresponding index from list1 of each number used in array2
3. Can only use each number in array2 only twice.

The data: I have three sets of data in one list and two arrays. First list is the names, second array is number, and third array is targets. list1 and array2 are the same length(55) but not array3.

```
list1 = ['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'ah', 'ai', 'aj', 'ak', 
'bc', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'bg', 'bh', 'bi', 'bj', 'bk', 'cd', 'ce', 
'cf', 'cg', 'ch', 'ci', 'cj', 'ck', 'de', 'df', 'dg', 'dh', 'di', 
'dj', 'dk', 'ef', 'eg', 'eh', 'ei', 'ej', 'ek', 'fg', 'fh', 'fi', 
'fj', 'fk', 'gh', 'gi', 'gj', 'gk', 'hi', 'hj', 'hk', 'ij', 'ik', 
'jk']
array2 = [39, 6, 29, 38, 2, 34, 7, 6, 2, 3, 37, 13, 20, 18, 4, 14, 
28, 2, 20, 25, 13, 38, 32, 28, 9, 7, 14, 11, 31, 29, 29, 39, 9, 35, 
14, 34, 23, 31, 11, 2, 37, 19, 18, 6, 5, 12, 6, 33, 30, 22, 38, 37, 
13, 31, 40]
array3 = [80, 74, 84, 89, 89, 78, 79, 85, 81, 89, 75, 86, 76, 71, 
82, 79, 75, 78, 83, 89]
```

The results I'm looking for are:

For 80 in array3, use 39+38+3, which would be 'ab', 'ae', 'ak' from list1.

For 74 in array3, use 39+32+2, which would be 'ab', 'cg', 'ek' from list1

and so on.

Im trying to find a pythonic way of solving this, using python3.x. I have looked into itertools.combinations/permutations and the knapsack problem. The Knapsack problem has come the closest to solving this but evaluates two values to get the best solution against a target and I only need one.
I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me(if you want to I won't stop you), rather I'm looking for someone with more experience then me to point me in the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: "Im trying to find a pythonic way of solving this" at first glance, the problem _may_ be small enough to brute-force (I haven't calculated out the complexity) in a reasonable amount of time. Any bigger; forget about it, you're on to heuristics.

Comment: Is there any size limits? If you're not worrying about extending the number count past 100 this can be quite easy. Otherwise it's an algorithm question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: Can an `array2` number be used twice for *each* `array3` number, or twice overall?  The latter is rather more complicated.

Comment: @DavisHerring `array2` number can only be used once per `array3` and twice overall.
@RockyLi Unfortunately the count in `array3` can go past 100 but I'm interested in how you would approach the problem.
@KlausD. I've messed with the Knapsack function but the problem I've ran into is it needs a `value` and a `weight` to work. I've tried modifying it to only use one of the aforementioned but it just doesn't work. That made me think I'm approaching the problem wrong, hence why I'm asking you smart folks here for advice on how to approach solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following algorithm searches e solution in the huge space of all triplets in `array2` for all targets in `array3`:

```
list1 = ['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'ah', 'ai', 'aj', 'ak', 'bc', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'bg', 'bh', 'bi', 'bj', 'bk', 'cd', 'ce', 'cf', 'cg', 'ch', 'ci', 'cj', 'ck', 'de', 'df', 'dg', 'dh', 'di', 'dj', 'dk', 'ef', 'eg', 'eh', 'ei', 'ej', 'ek', 'fg', 'fh', 'fi', 'fj', 'fk', 'gh', 'gi', 'gj', 'gk', 'hi', 'hj', 'hk', 'ij', 'ik', 'jk']
array2 = [39, 6, 29, 38, 2, 34, 7, 6, 2, 3, 37, 13, 20, 18, 4, 14, 28, 2, 20, 25, 13, 38, 32, 28, 9, 7, 14, 11, 31, 29, 29, 39, 9, 35, 14, 34, 23, 31, 11, 2, 37, 19, 18, 6, 5, 12, 6, 33, 30, 22, 38, 37, 13, 31, 40]
array3 = [80, 74, 84, 89, 89, 78, 79, 85, 81, 89, 75, 86, 76, 71, 82, 79, 75, 78, 83, 89]

import itertools
import numpy as np
import heapq
import copy

list1 = np.array(list1, dtype=str)
array2 = np.array(array2, dtype=int)
array3 = np.array(array3, dtype=int)

m, n = len(array2), len(array3)

combs = [[] for __ in range(n)]

maxuses = 2

combinations = set(map(tuple, itertools.combinations(list(range(m))*maxuses, 3)))
print(f'searching in {len(combinations)}! space')

def dist(a, b):
    return abs(a - b)

for i, target in enumerate(array3):
    for comb in map(list, combinations):
        combs[i].append((dist(target, sum(array2[comb])), comb))

    combs[i].sort(key=lambda item: item[0])

tested = set()

cost = 0
locs = [0]*n
used = {i: [] for i in range(m)}

for i in range(n):
    for value in combs[i][0][1]:
        used[value].append(i)
    cost += combs[i][0][0]

def priority(values):
    return (np.array(list(map(len, values)))**2).sum()

minheap = [(cost, priority(used.values()), locs, used)]

count = 0
while minheap:
    cost, __, locs, used = heapq.heappop(minheap)

    count += 1
    print(f'tested {count}, best cost {cost}, heap size {len(minheap)}')

    for key in used:
        if len(used[key]) > maxuses:
            loc1 = used[key][-1]
            loc2 = next(itertools.islice(filter(lambda x: x != loc1, used[key]), 0, None))

            print(f'value at {key} is used by {len(used[key])} combinations')

            # print(key, used[key])
            # print(loc1, combs[loc1][locs[loc1]][1])
            # print(loc2, combs[loc2][locs[loc2]][1])
            for value in combs[loc1][locs[loc1]][1]:
                used[value].remove(loc1)
            for value in combs[loc2][locs[loc2]][1]:
                used[value].remove(loc2)

            if loc1 < len(combinations)-1:
                cost1 = cost
                locs1 = list(locs)
                used1 = copy.deepcopy(used)

                cost1 -= combs[loc1][locs[loc1]][0]
                locs1[loc1] += 1
                cost1 += combs[loc1][locs[loc1]][0]

                for value in combs[loc1][locs1[loc1]][1]:
                    used1[value].append(loc1)
                for value in combs[loc2][locs1[loc2]][1]:
                    used1[value].append(loc2)

                if tuple(locs1) not in tested:
                    tested.add(tuple(locs1))
                    heapq.heappush(minheap, (cost1, priority(used1.values()), locs1, used1))

            if loc2 < len(combinations)-1:
                cost2 = cost
                locs2 = list(locs)
                used2 = copy.deepcopy(used)

                cost2 -= combs[loc2][locs2[loc2]][0]
                locs2[loc2] += 1
                cost2 += combs[loc2][locs2[loc2]][0]

                for value in combs[loc1][locs2[loc1]][1]:
                    used2[value].append(loc1)
                for value in combs[loc2][locs2[loc2]][1]:
                    used2[value].append(loc2)

                if tuple(locs2) not in tested:
                    tested.add(tuple(locs2))
                    heapq.heappush(minheap, (cost2, priority(used2.values()), locs2, used2))
            break
    else:
        print(f'found a solution with {cost} cost:')
        print(locs)

        for i , target in enumerate(array3):
            print(f'{target}\t~=\t ', end='')
            print(*array2[combs[i][locs[i]][1]], sep='+', end=' ')
            print('\t(', end='')
            print(*list1[combs[i][locs[i]][1]], sep=', ', end='')
            print(')')

        exit()
```

It will return (one of) the triplets combinations that minimize the cost and only uses each number in `array2` at most twice.

Because you didn't specified the criteria for the *best* solution when there isn't a exact one, I assumed the absolute difference between the sum of a triplet and its target, but you can change that in `dist`.

It works incredibly fast with your example (<10s), but I have guarantees it will be as fast as that, and you'll probably need some randomization. But this is one solution for your example:

```
80      ~=       28+23+29       (ch, eh, dg)
74      ~=       29+39+6        (dg, di, ai)
84      ~=       13+33+38       (ij, gj, hj)
89      ~=       37+39+13       (bc, di, ij)
89      ~=       30+40+19       (gk, jk, fh)
78      ~=       7+40+31        (ah, jk, ei)
79      ~=       31+18+30       (ei, fi, gk)
85      ~=       13+37+35       (ce, fg, dk)
81      ~=       18+32+31       (bf, cg, df)
89      ~=       34+20+35       (eg, be, dk)
75      ~=       13+28+34       (bd, bi, ag)
86      ~=       18+39+29       (bf, ab, dh)
76      ~=       29+38+9        (ad, hj, dj)
71      ~=       14+37+20       (bh, bc, be)
82      ~=       29+20+33       (dh, bk, gj)
79      ~=       14+37+28       (ef, hk, ch)
75      ~=       28+9+38        (bi, ci, ae)
78      ~=       34+38+6        (eg, cf, gi)
83      ~=       29+31+23       (ad, df, eh)
89      ~=       37+38+14       (hk, cf, ef)
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes each element (with distinct index) in array2 is used only once (you could extend to element repeats), and that you don't care which three elements you use:

```
# target is the desired number from array3
def triplet_sum(list1, array2, target):
    n = len(array2)
    a = [(i, array2[i]) for i in range(n)]
    a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    j = 1
    i = j-1
    k = j+1
    best_sum = sys.maxsize
    best_answer = None
    while j < n:
        while i >= 0 and k < n:
            x = a[i][1]
            y = a[j][1]
            z = a[k][1]
            S = x + y + z
            candidate = [(x, list1[a[i][0]]), (y, list1[a[j][0]]), (z, list1[a[k][0]])]
            if S == target:
                return candidate
            elif S > target:
                i -= 1
            else:
                k += 1
            if abs(target - best_sum) > abs(target - S):
                best_sum = S
                best_answer = candidate
        j += 1
        i = j-1
        k = j+1
    return best_answer
```

Example output:

```
# Closest match
triplet_sum(list1, array2, 5)
[(2, 'af'), (2, 'aj'), (2, 'bj')]
# An exact match
triplet_sum(list1, array2, 80)
[(20, 'be'), (20, 'bk'), (40, 'jk')]
```

I'm just moving my middle choice `j` along the sorted list `a`, always going left with `i` if `S` is too high, and to the right with `k` if `S` is too low. *O(n^2)* complexity at a glance.